# declaration of 'x' has a different language linkage

Tags: c++, c

When I build source, it throws an error: `declaration of 'globalMemTrace' has a different language linkage`

```
#ifdef MEMDEBUG_SIMULATIONS
#include "mem-trace.h"
MemTrace *globalMemTrace;
#endif

// omitted unrelated parts    

int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interp)
{
#ifdef MEMDEBUG_SIMULATIONS
    extern MemTrace *globalMemTrace;
    globalMemTrace = new MemTrace;
#endif
}
```

I've googled several times for it. Some said that it is due to a bug if `clang` and some said tricks in using `extern` differently may solve it.

But since I am not such a profession, I've tried some of them and failed to solve it. Is there any nice way to deal with it?

It's written in C++ and the problem occurs at `extern MemTrace *globalMemTrace;`

Comment: In what line the error is? is it `C` or `C++`? they are to different languages.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's C++. and `extern MemTrace *globalMemTrace;` has a problem.

Answer (score 8):

C++ offers linkage between C++ and non-C++ languages in the from of language linkage.

For example

```
//  in C++ program
extern "C" int displayfoo(const char *);
int main() {
    return displayfoo("hello");
}

/*  in C program     */
#include <stdio.h>
extern int displayfoo(const char * str) {
    while (*str) {
       putchar(*str);
       putchar(' ');
       ++str;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

You are using a C function `displayfoo` from c++ code, So you need to tell the compiler/linker that it is from different language. That is done by extern "C".

In your code `MemTrace *globalMemTrace;` may be declared previously in a C code or a C block inside c++, So you need to declare it like

```
extern "C" MemTrace *globalMemTrace;
```

Answer (score 3):

It means that the actual variable was declared in C code, or at least wrapped in an `extern "C"` block in C++ code, but the `extern` is declared in C++ code, thus it cannot link to the variable as they exist in different languages.

Have a look at these articles:

[Language linkage](http://scv.bu.edu/computation/bluegene/IBMdocs/compiler/xlc-8.0/html/language/ref/cplr020.htm)

[Linking C and C++ code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C++#Linking_C_and_C.2B.2B_code)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this name is already declared as having C language linkage.

```
extern "C" MemTrace *globalMemTrace;
```